# The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi every one I am getting the following error: "The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context"

```
// namespaces
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace Database1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static string GetConnectionString(string strConnection)
        {
            //variable to hold our connection string for returning it

            string strReturn = "";
            //check to see if the user provided a connection string name
            //this is for if your application has more than one connection string

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strConnection)) //a connection string name was        
            {
                //get the connection string by the name provided
                strReturn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[strConnection].ConnectionString;

            }
            else //no connection string name was provided
            {
                //get the default connection string
                strReturn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
            }
            //return the connection string to the calling method
            return strReturn;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of .NET Framework and Visual Studio are you using?

ConfigurationManager is only available in .NET 2 and above. If you are using .NET Framework 1.x and Visual Studio 2002/2003, you won't be able to use this class at all.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Click "Other versions" link in the top of this page and you will see all versions it supports.

Comment: I used .net core , in my case also can't resolved that plz help

Comment: There was no .NET Core in 2012, so definitely this answer won't apply to it. Use Google and it can easily lead you to the right answer.

Answer (score 12):

Have you added a reference to System.Configuration.dll?

Comment: No i did not add this reference and i am not able to find this reference in the add reference tab how to find it?

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't the message be something like type or namespace `ConfigurationManager` not found in this case ?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and the .NET Framework are you using?

Answer (score 6):

You have to add reference to System.Configuration.dll

When you right click and click on the Add reference button

Click .Net tab in the open popup

There you should be able to locate the System.Configuration.dll file

Comment: No its not there i have tried it but i am not able find System.Configuration.dll file in this tab

Comment: strange you can't find it there ? maybe you need to restart VS

Answer (score 3):

This is the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Configuration.dll
```

also you can add reference to the `:System:`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Configuration.Install.dll
```

(hope it helps :))

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue using .Net Core, but using .NET Running `Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` in Package manager solved it for me.